# How to prevent apps from opening the browser in Windows XP?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, browser

It's quite annoying during an uninstall or application exit to have the app open a web browser with a survey or the like.  I'd like to prevent this from happening, if possible?  There's [a similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/577975/prevent-applications-from-opening-browser) up already, but it doesn't have any good answers :(

I presume this question is generic to most recent versions of Windows up to 8 as well, but since the machine is XPSP3 I thought it best to be as specific as possible.

Comment: only an application firewall would be capable of preventing the uninstaller from performing an action like opening an external program or asking the system to open an object that the system has associated with an application. Additionally, since the uninstaller is performing a trusted operation like deleting files and resources, you would probably have to specifically deny the uninstaller the privilege. you could try severing the association between urls and your browser, but that would be global and affect all applications.

Comment: Please don't post duplicate questions. If you'd like newer/better/different answers to the existing question, [place a bounty on it](http://superuser.com/help/bounty) instead.